# shift invariance of integral involving nested cosines

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral:
$$\int^\pi_0 \sin(2x) \cos(a\cos(x-\phi)) dx,$$
which I can reduce to a sum of two contributions involving
$$\int^{\pi-\phi}_{-\phi} \sin(2y) \cos(a\cos(y)) dy$$ and
$$\int^{\pi-\phi}_{-\phi} \cos(2y) \cos(a\cos(y)) dy$$
where $y=x-\phi$. 
I would like to use tabulated results that exist for the latter two integrals, but for the special case $\phi=0$ only. So I need to prove that my integrals are shift invariant with respect to $\phi$.

My reasoning is that, taking the integrand in the upper and lower limits are equal, i.e., 
$$\sin(2(\pi-\phi)) \cos(a\cos(\pi-\phi)) = \sin(2(-\phi)) \cos(a\cos(-\phi)) $$
and
$$\cos(2(\pi-\phi)) \cos(a\cos(\pi-\phi)) = \cos(2(-\phi)) \cos(a\cos(-\phi)) $$
and this for any $\phi$.

Is it correct and sufficient to conclude rigorously that the integrals are shift invariant under $\phi$ so that I can use the tabulated result valid for $\phi=0$?

Comment: More directly, note that the $\cos(2y)$ has a period of $\pi$. Further, $\cos( a\cos (\pi + y)) = \cos (-a\cos y) = \cos (a \cos y),$ since $\cos$ is an even function. Since both functions have a period of $\pi,$ so does their product,  and you're integrating over one period, so it doesn't matter where you start.